# MySql using user defined variables in an update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

How can I use user defined variables in a MySql update statement? By user defined variables, i'm referring to the `@v:=`.

The statement below works fine without the user defined variables, but not with them.

```
update amga a left join amgb b on a.itemTempId = b.itemTempId
set @i:= concat(a.itemCountry,'-',a.id), a.itemId = @i, b.itemId = @i 
where a.itemId is null or b.itemId is null;
```

I'll be using this with php PDO later.

**This works, but does use user defined variables**

```
update amga a left join amgb b on a.itemTempId = b.itemTempId
set a.itemId = concat(a.itemCountry,'-',a.id), b.itemId = concat(a.itemCountry,'-',a.id) 
where a.itemId is null or b.itemId is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following syntax:

```
update amga a left join amgb b on a.itemTempId = b.itemTempId
set a.itemId = (@i:= concat(a.itemCountry,'-',a.id)), b.itemId = @i 
where a.itemId is null or b.itemId is null;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93eb4/1)</kbd>

Comment: You can avoid the user variable here AFAIK, with `set a.itemId = concat(a.itemCountry,'-',a.id), b.itemId = a.itemId ` since MySQL updates use the updated values in the next "SET" assignments